# Set Containers array into Stack view Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to display a ListView Horizontal n times in Stack or Row. But in the end all the ListViews are piled up instead shows one by one from top to bottom.

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Prueba para trabajar en el proyecto"),
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      _crearLista(),
      _crearLista(),
      _crearLista(),
      _crearLista(),
      _crearLista(),
      //_crearLoading(),
    ],
  ),
);
}
Widget _crearLista() {
return Container(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: _listaNumeros.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              //return image
            },
            controller: _scrollController,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Any suggestions? please. I want to show all the LsitViews.

Answer (score 1):

A `Stack` widget puts its children above each other (overlapped or piled up) at the left top corner of the stack by default. Unless you position each child using a `Positioned` or `Align` widget. To have all the children one below the other (starting from top of the screen towards bottom), you need to use a `Column` instead of `Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

Stack children behave like layers, one covers second, etc.

If you want one child exactly below another, there is ListView and Column